# padding at last member of c struct

Tags: c, struct, padding, memory-alignment

I always assume, as they said here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment, "It is important to note that the last member is padded with the number of bytes required so that the total size of the structure should be a multiple of the largest alignment of any structure member"

So for the struct like this, its size should be 16 at a 32 processor

```
typedef struct
{
   double   s;  /* 8 bytes */
   char     c;  /* 7 bytes padding at the end of make the total size 8*2 */
} structa_t;
```

So I was quite surprised to the size is 12 instead of 16!! Why is that ? Can someone cast some light on it ?

```
sizeof(double) = 8
sizeof(structa_t) = 12
```

BTW, so system info

```
$ uname -a
Linux 2.6.18-8.el5xen #1 SMP Thu Mar 15 21:02:53 EDT 2007 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.1.1 20070105 (Red Hat 4.1.1-52)
```

Comment: You must mean bytes where you've said bits

Comment: Maybe simply `double` only needs to be aligned on a four-byte boundary?

Comment: You missed a closing `*/` for your comment.

Comment: Thanks. I have corrected those typos

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key wording here is:

> ...the total size of the structure should be a multiple of the largest **alignment** of any structure member...

On your system, the aligment of a `double` is 4, not 8.

If you wait for C1x, you can use the `_Alignof` operator (similar to `sizeof`).  On your system,

```
sizeof(double) == 8
_Alignof(double) == 4
```

You can test the alignment in a more primitive way in C89,

```
#include <stdlib.h>
struct char_double { char x; double y; };
#define DOUBLE_ALIGNMENT offsetof(struct char_double, y)
```

Or with a macro,

```
#define alignof(x) offsetof(struct { char a; x b; }, b)
```

Comment: If you can't wait for C1x, you can try `#define alignof(type) offsetof(struct { char c; type t; }, t)` and usually get a good answer. I'm not 100% sure it's guaranteed to work but it seems to.

Comment: Thanks. I further check that wiki and just like you said it did say "A double (eight bytes) will be 8-byte aligned on Windows and 4-byte aligned on Linux".

Comment: @Chris Lutz: I hesitated to suggest that option because I suspected some implementations wouldn't support it, but I realize that was an error.

Comment: @Dietrich - I had a moment about a month ago where I went "wait, is it always portable to use inline-defined `struct` types inside `offsetof`?" and stopped using it, but I can't remember what made me think that, and I can't think of any reason why it wouldn't be.

Comment: @Chris Lutz: What made me think it was wondering if the structure was expanded twice inside the macro, and then it would define two separate types instead of one.  However, the standard macro implementation only expands it once, and it's more sensible to use a builtin anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia isn't a particularly reliable source for details like this.

In this case, the size of the largest item in the struct forms a (fairly hard) upper bound in the size to which the struct as a whole *might* get padded -- but the implementation is free to use less padding than that if it sees fit. In many cases, an "N-bit" processor, the maximum padding that can do any good for a particular struct will be the smaller of: 1) the largest item in the struct, or 2) the 'bitness' of the processor itself (so with a 32-bit processor, you frequently don't need/want to pad to larger than 32-bit boundaries, even for data items larger than that).

Comment: No, Wikipedia's wording is right, it just hinges on one word. See @Dietrich's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Its because in your case the structure is aligned to word boundaries (where a word = 4 bytes).

Comment: @Qiulang: Alignment is not identical to size.  Alignment must evenly divide the size - so for an 8 byte double, possible alignments are 1, 2, 4 and 8.  In your case, it is apparently 4.

Comment: @Qiulang - Read that carefully: "...the lowest common multiple of the **alignments** of all of the members..." Not the _sizes_ of the members, the _alignments_ of them. A data type can have a large size but not need to be perfectly aligned to that size. In a 32-bit architecture, `int64_t` won't gain any performance benefits for being aligned to 8 bytes, since there wouldn't be any 8-byte instructions to operate on it. So it only needs 4-byte alignment.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, as I mentioned above "A double (eight bytes) will be 8-byte aligned on Windows and 4-byte aligned on Linux". I tested that on window before so I got the impression that the alignment of double is 8. And MSDN also confirmed that, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa296569%28v=vs.60%29.aspx.  So I wrongly assumed that was the case for linux as well.

Comment: @caf "Alignment must evenly divide the size" No, it doesn't have to. 10-byte extended doubles are typically aligned to 4-byte boundaries.

Comment: @Pascal Cuoq: Yes, it does.  If you had an array of such 10-byte extended doubles, and `a[0]` was aligned on a 4-byte boundary, then `a[1]` would only be aligned on a 2-byte boundary.  If the type requires 4-byte alignment, then its size must be a multiple of this - so even if only 10 bytes of it were meaningful, it would need to include 2 padding bytes to bring its size up to 12.

Comment: @caf Ah, yes, I didn't think that through. You are right: when `extended double` has a 4-byte alignment requirement, then it must be extended to 12 bytes with 2 bytes of padding.